# How to find the transfer function for steady state?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance, steady-state

I can not find the transfer function for sinusoidal input
could you please help me find out the solution or at least where to start!
i have found the transfer function Vo(s)/Vi(s)=1/(2j+1)
but still can not solve for Vout(t) ?

[image]